# Vigor2700, tenda n30 wds

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge, wds

Ii would like to extends my WiFi signal from Vigor2700 using Tenda N30, but it's not working.

I have never did something like this before, but i think that problem is not in tenda as it looks like it is extending the signal because there is only 1 WiFi and I can join it.

But when I'm joined to tenda and not vigor I get limited access.

The first two screens are tenda settings, the rest are vigor.

[image: Perfect screens]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more setting is needed, Tenda needs to know it is joining an access point using WiFi not a cable. This one thing is missing in user manual
[image: Tenda settings]